# Replaying "active" keyboard grabs with Xlib on Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-events, xlib

I've been using Xlib's XGrabKey to track input events for single keys with XAllowEvents=ReplayPointer so that the target window also gets the event.

I need to do this for the entire keyboard, probably using [XGrabKeyboard](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/XGrabKeyboard.3.html#toc3), but XGrabKeyboard is an active grab and according to the documentation and experience [ReplayPointer](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XAllowEvents.html) doesn't work for active grabs.

Is there any way I can replay or otherwise forward the event to the target window even with an active grab?

I won't have root access, so alternatives using /dev/input/event* are unfortunately not options.

Thanks!